# How to get a table or dataframe as a output in R shiny app using selectInput function?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I want to get a table output using `selectInput` function.
I have to import(not upload) different csv files in place of object error1,2,3,4 but when I am doing this I am not getting proper output in `mainPanel`. Please help me in importing csv files in right place so that I could get table as an output in mainpanel.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(
titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  tags$head(
    tags$style("body{backgroud-color: pink;}")),
  selectInput("mydata", "ERROR MESSAGE:",
              choices =   c("Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31"="error1",
                         "Filter paper wrong or not inserted-Error number 30 / 20"="error2", 

                         "Device is heating up (working temp. not reached yet) Heating Option-Error number 32 / 51"="error3",

                         "Door is open (Timeout key)-Error number 15 / 100"="error4")                 
  )
),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel(h2("TABLE", style = "color:red"), verbatimTextOutput ("mydata")),
  #tabPanel(h2("ERROR", style = "color:red"), verbatimTextOutput("ERROR")),
  tags$head(tags$style("#mydata{color:blue;
                       font-size: 17px;
                       font-style: bold
                       }")) 
  ),
  width = 12)   
   )))

 server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){   

output$mydata <-renderPrint ({
      input$mydata
      })    
}) 

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. What is your expected proper output? For uploading a csv you can try [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html).

Comment: In error1 there is a dataframe and i want that dataframe as output. For example from sidebarpanel if i choose "Clamping lever closing not detected-Error number 7 / 31" then i should get a dataframe which is stored in the object error1 as my output in main panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `render` function actually returns the selected item as a string from your `input` and not the object itself. You can wrap all the objects in a `list` or use `get`:

**Option 1**

```
# put all objects in a list
mDat <- list(error1 = cars, error2 = airquality, error3 = chickwts, error4 = co2)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
   output$mydata <- renderPrint ({
      mDat[[input$mydata]]
   })    
})
```

**Option 2**

```
# This assumes that you have the objects error1, ..., error4 in the environment

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
   output$mydata <- renderPrint ({
      get(input$mydata)
   })    
})
```